# Where is the variable named "global" coming from

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am refactoring a React 15 application (built with Webpack 2 and Babel) and I have noticed a lot of references to a global variable called `global` e.g. `global.location`. It's an alias for `window`, but I cannot find any code or configuration where the assignment occurs.

The Chrome devtools console can't access `global` so it is contained inside the modules that webpack generates. It's a very overloaded search term and I haven't had any luck tracking it down on Google.

Where is `global` coming from? Is there any benefit using it in a web application over `window`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `global` variable is handled specially by Webpack, **not by Babel**. Webpack's configuration file may contain a `node` section, which controls the polyfilling of various node objects, like `global`. Unless otherwise specified, `global` will be rewritten by webpack to mean `window`.

Example `webpack.config.js` turning off `global` rewriting:

```
module.exports = {
  node: {
    global: false
  }
}
```

[Documentation from project wiki.](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#node)